# What is the formal name of this logical fallacy?

Tags: logic, fallacies

The fallacy goes like this.

> The drunkard drinks a bottle of tequila with ice on Monday and gets drunk. The drunkard drinks a bottle of vodka with ice on Tuesday and gets drunk. The drunkard drinks a bottle of whiskey with ice on Wednesday and gets drunk. He concludes that the ice got him drunk.

What is the name of this drunk's fallacy?

Comment: It's called inferring causality from correlation.

Comment: [Correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation), Latin name *cum hoc ergo propter hoc* ('with this, therefore because of this').

Comment: @Conifold It would be nice if you could expand on *cum hoc ergo propter hoc* and why it is a violation of syllogistic logic in a full answer. I promise to give you the green checkmark.

Comment: This is an informal fallacy so syllogistic is not relevant. Many informally valid inferences violate it too, and many formal ones are not even expressible in it. Wikipedia already has a long article on *cum hoc* and how it can go wrong, including discussion of circumstances when correlation might imply causation heuristically. Why do a redux here?

Comment: I don't believe this is a fallacy; rather it is a mere _error_.